# Convert Javascript Float32Array to c# FileStream sending throw SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

To follow my previous question:
[WebRTC and Asp.NetCore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220281/webrtc-and-asp-netcore)

I have an Angular App which record the microphone and, using SignalR, send a Float32Array to my .Net Core Api which will save it in a wav File.

```
public class BaseHub : Hub
{
    public void SendStream(object o)
    {
        float[] floatArray = (float[])o; //the conversion doesnt work
        byte[] bytes = new byte[floatArray .Length * sizeof(float)];
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("./mywavfile.wav", FileMode.Append))
        {
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

*Watch result of o in Visual Studio*
[image: Watch result]

*Content of the resultView of o*
[image: content of Result View]

How can I convert a Float32Array from javascript to float[] in c# sending throw SignalR?

Comment: It's a JObject. Cast to JArray and call `ToObject<float[]>();`.

Comment: I tried, it doesnt work. 
(o as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray) => null

But, there is this thing I notice
(o as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject).First =>  {"0": 0}
    ChildrenTokens: {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.JPropertyList}
    Count: 1
    First: {0}
    HasValues: true
    Last: {0}
    Name: "0"
    Next: {"1": 0}
    Parent: {{
  "0": 0,
  "1": 0,
  "2": 0, [...]

Comment: Indeed, you can't cast JObject to JArray. They both inherit from JContainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the JObject. here is an example:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // something like this is coming as the request
        var str = "{\"0\":0.0,\"1\":0.1,\"2\":0.2,\"3\":0.3,\"4\":0.4,\"5\":0.5}";

        // you are getting a JObject, this is the type of "object o", 
        // I am loading one here using the same schema we see in your example.
        var jobj = JObject.Load(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(str)));

        // now we simply need to parse out all the values. 
        // Below are 3 options in order from "least amount of built in functions"
        // to most built in usage.
        // personally, I use option 3

        // option 1:
        // loop over the children as properties.
        var output = new List<float>();
        foreach (var prop in jobj.Children<JProperty>())
        {               
            output.Add(float.Parse(prop.Value.ToString()));
        }

        // option 2:
        // convert directly using linq
        float [] outputAsArray = jobj.Children<JProperty>().Select(x => float.Parse(x.Value.ToString())).ToArray();

        //option 3 cast and convert using Json.Net
        outputAsArray = jobj.Children<JProperty>().Values<float>().ToArray();
    }
```